# [Celery]: Trouble with memory when send many task

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, celery, django-celery

I using celery process many task on many machines but i have a trouble with memory.
I have a file 6 GB text id, i read file and get id to send it to task on other machine.

```
 with open(source_file) as file:
    for row in file:
        row = json.loads(row)
        if row['oid']:
            app.send_task(name='test',
                          queue='test',
                          routing_key='test',
                          args=(row['oid'],))
```

But trouble is memory ram grown up to fast. When i comment send_task code , memory ram is normal . I think when i send task to fast, memory not release memory. Sr my English not good

Answer (score 0):

1) you can buy more RAM

2) you are writing tasks to RAM so quickly and the worker on other side is not able to process them, then you can slow down the celery task sender with simple sleep method

```
    if row['oid']:
        app.send_task(name='test',
                      queue='test',
                      routing_key='test',
                      args=(row['oid'],))
        import time
        time.sleep(1) # sleep one second
```

3) you could save only the `row[oid']` to RAM using Redis for example and without celery. And the remote worker would listen for that data ([Pub/sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub))

Comment: Thank u ! i using sleep method to keep slow push task to Ram